# How to change the default background color and font color in the following overleaf template?

Tags: beamer, color

I would like to change the default background colour to white and the default font colour to black, how may I do it?

I don't know the location of the code where I can make the changes but by the figure [image]

we can understand the question that the background is dark and the text appears in white colour. how do I change the colour of the background and text as well? Please go through the following overleaf link:

Anyone with this link can edit this project
https://www.overleaf.com/8862493198fmktstqnvbvj
Anyone with this link can view this project
https://www.overleaf.com/read/tkwwxgccrnjt

Comment: Please add code examples directly to the question, instead of posting a link to an Overleaf project that might stop working at some point. And also make a smaller example, you really don't need more than preamble and one or two slides.

Comment: Sorry, location of code I don't know.

Comment: I mean the actual LaTeX code, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`,  used to generate the presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example use

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\input{chapters/preamble}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg= blue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg= blue}
```

...

[image: a]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @sanjay gupta In your example you can edit `preamble.tex` in the subdirectory `chapters`